# Заменить итератор циклом

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как переписать фрагмент кода, используя вместо итератора цикл:

```
public boolean comp() 
{
    ArrayList<One> oneList = squar.getOneList();
    One one = oneList.get(oneList.size() - 1);
    Iterator itr = oneList.iterator();
    while.hasNext())
    {
        if(itr.next().equals(cell) && itr.hasNext())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean comp() {
    ArrayList<One> oneList = squar.getOneList();
    for (int i = 0; i < oneList.size(); i++) {
            if (oneList.get(i).equals(cell) && i<oneList.size()-1)return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```